# SwiftUI ListRowInsets issue above a certain number

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to add a custom inset to the items in a list.

Using `listRowInsets` a simple change from 10.0 to 11.0 pixels causes a massive increase in the design:

`.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 10, bottom: 24, trailing: 24))`

Here I have a leading inset of 10, and this is the result:

[image]

Now if I change the number to 11 is actually increases by several pixels:

`.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 11, bottom: 24, trailing: 24))`

[image]

I tried setting all insets to zero and using padding instead, but I get the same result when increasing from 16 to 17 pixels.

Here is the full code:

```swift
        ZStack {
            // Hide navigation arrows from list items.
            NavigationLink(value: note.id) {
                EmptyView()
            }.hidden()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text(note.title)
                    .font(.custom("Inter", size: 16))
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .foregroundColor(.TextColorPrimary)
                
                Text("test ")
                    .font(.custom("Inter", size: 16))
                    .foregroundColor(.TextColorSecondary)
            }
        }
        // Add padding around the list item.
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 11, bottom: 24, trailing: 24))
        // Add trailing space in the list row separator.
        .alignmentGuide(.listRowSeparatorTrailing) { viewDimensions in
            return viewDimensions[.trailing]
        }
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden, edges: .top)
        .listRowSeparatorTint(.DividerColorPrimary)
```

Any idea how to solve this?